# Update Redmine Ticket via REST API with .json file in Powershell

Tags: json, rest, powershell

```
#Create an object to store the headers
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],
[String]]"
#Add Header Name, Value
$headers.Add("X-Redmine-API-key",'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
$headers.Add("Content-Type",'application/json')

$uri="https://redmine.company.com/issues"

$json=C:\scripts\ticket.json
#Calls the API 
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Headers $headers -Uri $uri 


Invoke-RestMethod : Page not found
The page you were trying to access doesn't exist or has been removed.
Back
At line:21 char:8
+ $oData=Invoke-RestMethod -Method Put -Headers $headers -Uri $uri -
ContentType 'a ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: 
(System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :
```

As I stated in the title I'm trying to use REST API to update a ticket with a json file using powershell.  The error claims that the URI I'm using isn't correct, but if Modify the code and use GET it works just fine.  Has anyone tried this or have something similiar I could use as a starting point?

Comment: https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/invoke-restmethod-powershell-examples/

Answer (score 0):

[According to their documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api)

[Update: PUT update issue](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues)

```
$Headers = @{ 'X-Redmine-API-key' = 'xxx' }
$Body = Get-Content -Path C:\scripts\ticket.json -Raw
$Uri = 'https://redmine.company.com/issues/<ENTERIDHERE>.json'

$R = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Body $Body -Method PUT -Uri $Uri -ContentType application/json

$R
```